# Modifying the number input to be specific pattern format?

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, windows-scripting

How can I make the below code to format the Phone Number to output the result in:
**+44 123 456 789** instead of *+44 123456789* ?

```
Function Format-TelephoneNumber {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('Number')]
        [string]$TelephoneNumber,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [string]$DefaultCountryCode = '+44'
    )
    Process {
        $formattedNumber = $TelephoneNumber -replace '[\x09 ]'
        If ($formattedNumber -match '\A(?<CountryCode>\+[1-9]\d|0)(?<Number>\d*)\Z') {
            If ($Matches['CountryCode'] -eq '0') {
                $countryCode = $defaultCountryCode
            }
            Else {
                $countryCode = $Matches['CountryCode']
            }
            $formattedNumber = $countryCode + ' ' + $Matches['Number']
            $formattedNumber
        }
        Else {
            Write-Error "Unable to parse the string '$($number)' as telephone number!"
        }
    }
}

'+33 123456789', '0123456789', '0 123 456 789' | Format-TelephoneNumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, just joining the values with a range from the array:

```
Function Format-TelephoneNumber {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('Number')]
        [string]$TelephoneNumber,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [string]$DefaultCountryCode = '+44'
    )
    Process {
        $formattedNumber = $TelephoneNumber -replace '[\x09 ]'
        If (-not ([string]::ISNULLOREMPTY($TelephoneNumber))) {
            If ($formattedNumber -match '\A(?<CountryCode>\+[1-9]\d|0)(?<Number>\d*)\Z') {
                If ($Matches['CountryCode'] -eq '0') {
                    $countryCode = $defaultCountryCode
                }
                Else {
                    $countryCode = $Matches['CountryCode']
                }
                $formattedNumber = $countryCode + ' ' 
                $formattedNumber += -join $Matches['Number'][0..2] + ' '
                $formattedNumber += -join $Matches['Number'][3..5] + ' '
                $formattedNumber += -join $Matches['Number'][6..8]
                $formattedNumber
            }
            Else {
                Write-Error "Unable to parse the string '$($number)' as telephone number!"
            }
        }
    }
}

'+33 123456789', '0123456789', '0 123 456 789' | Format-TelephoneNumber
```

Output:

```
+33 123 456 789
+44 123 456 789
+44 123 456 789
```

Comment: Owain, thank you for the great reply, it works very well.

Comment: Owain, so how do I use it with the variable?
$adUser.mobile | Format-TelephoneNumber
Format-TelephoneNumber : Unable to parse the string '' as telephone number!
At line:39 char:18
+ $adUser.mobile | Format-TelephoneNumber
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Format-TelephoneNumber

Comment: Remove  [string] from your paramater declaration of $Telephone number and try again.

Comment: Are any of them Null? you may need to strip out any null values before you try parse them

Comment: No, there aren't any null values since this is the Telephone Attribute in the AD.

Comment: Passing an array of custom objects works fine for me, can you try it with my updated code. If it doesn't work, please send me the format of the number that it is failing on.